# How to pass regex expression in JSON to API?

Tags: javascript, json, regex, string, object

How can I pass RegEx in JSON to API without stringify it? Below is two code that refer what i want and what actually passing to API. I don't need to convert to stringify. Thanks in advance

```
//JSON I want to pass
{
    "data": {
        "type": "wood-species",
        "attributes": {
            "description": "test126",
            "abbreviation": /([A - Z])\ w +/  <-REGEX that i want to pass
        }
    }
    }
```

```
//JSON that actually pass
{
    "data": {
        "type": "wood-species",
        "attributes": {
            "description": "test126",
            "abbreviation": {}   <-REGEX that actually pass(making regex an empty object)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you're asking why JSON doesn't allow you to store types it does not support.  Answer: Because it doesn't support them.  Convert it to a string.

Comment: without stringify i think it is not possible , you have to pass as a string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't store a regex in a JSON string. You'd need to store it as an actual string and recreate it on the receiving end with the `RegExp` constructor (also slice off the leading and trailing slashes `/`).

```js
const obj = {
  "abbreviation": "/([A - Z])\w+/"
};

const stringified = JSON.stringify(obj);
const regex = new RegExp(JSON.parse(stringified).abbreviation.slice(1, -1));
console.log(regex);
```