# Share regex from backend to client side

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to create a regex in backend and share it to the client side for validation.

So, while the below works in client side

```
/^\d{0,10}$/.test('X')
```

since the backend can only return the regex as string, the below fails when it is string

```
"/^\d{0,10}$/".test('X')
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: `new RegExp('^\\d{0,10}$')` or ```new RegExp(String.raw`^\d{0,10}$`)```?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass regex expression in JSON to API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56471002/how-to-pass-regex-expression-in-json-to-api)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JS can deal with string regular expressions like you want, but you just need to parse that string with a `RexExp` object.

```js
var regex_str_from_server = "^\\d{0,10}$";
var regex = new RegExp(regex_str_from_server);

console.log('X', regex.test('X'));
console.log('45', regex.test('45'));
```

Just keep in mind that when using a string regex, you do not need the `/` slashes at the beginning and end, and any `\` slashes (like where you use `\d`)  must be escaped by adding another slash so it looks like `\\d` in your regex string.

The reason for escaping the slashes is that you are now inside of a string and any slash + the next character is treated like a control character, like how you would use `\n` for a line break.  Since you actually want the slash to appear in your regex string, you escape the slash with another slash.  You can see what I mean if you try to create the regex string without the extra slash, the first one is not present because it was not escaped!

[image: Example of regex string creating with and without escaping slash]

Comment: Thanks a lot...but could you please clarify regarding the start ^ and end $...Also in which case are the / needed in beginning and end ? Also when is new RegExp needed...coz i assume in few cases we can do .test() without new RegExp.

Comment: @copenndthagen The slashes are simple a way to "wrapping" a regex in JS, much like you use quotes to wrap a string.  But a `RegExp` object can also use a string like we are doing here.  The `^` and `$` characters are part of the actual regex pattern, so use them if you need to in your pattern.  That part of a regex pattern does not change between using the slashes or the quotes to wrap your regex pattern.

Comment: And just to be clear, the two ways to write your exact pattern are as you have written it with the wrapping forward-slashes: `/^\d{0,10}$/` or using a string, but with escaped back-slashes inside it: `"^\\d{0,10}$"` Those two should be have identically.